# Reuse fields in an ASP.NET form

Tags: asp.net

I have an online form that collects the user's contact information.  Typical stuff - first & last name, address, city, state, zip, etc.

At one point in the process, they can enter information for **another** person as well.  At that point, I show a modal popup with the very same fields for this other person.

I hate the repetition of the fields in my ASCX file.  I'd like to define a single block of fields and show them in different contexts.

A twist to the plot is that the admin of the site can configure which fields are visible for each of the two contexts.

For example, they might say for the primary user, we want to ask for phone number, but we don't want to show that field for the additional people.  In that situation, the phone number field would be visible for the main form, but hidden in the modal popup.

So the question is: What is the best way to reuse the same fields in different places of an ASP.NET form?

Comment: Just make another ASCX control for the group of controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another flag to your user control

Note : this flag must be declared as public property

```
public bool Flag 
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

Your User control

First instance : `<UCTagPrefix:UCTagName runat="server" id="" Flag="true"/>`

Second instance : `<UCTagPrefix:UCTagName runat="server" id="" Flag="false"/>`

you can use another type if you want, this sample is based on boolean

Adapt the behavior of your user control with the value of your flag , in your code behind

Answer (score 0):

If admin wants to configure visibility of each field, I think it would be better to add the field list to a database table like `fieldName, userType1 (bit), userType2 (bit),...` and then add the value `0 or 1` (Admin could do this via interface).

When you load the control get the corresponding values by passing userType to the database (stored procedure or query) and set visibility of each field accordingly.

Comment: Actually I'm doing something very much like that.  Right now the admin configures the "shown" fields for the primary person, and the "shown" fields for the additional people.  Both sets of shown/hidden fields are stored in the database.  The part I dont' like is code that ends up like this: MainFirstName.Visible = GetMainFirstNameVisible();  AdditionalFirstName.Visible = GetAdditionalFirstNameVisible();      i'd rather have just one set of fields, which are shown/hidden dependign on the context.

Comment: How about using a `GridView` control for those fileds (col1 for Labels and col2 for TextBoxes)? Then you can use above query results as datasource like `GridView.DataSource = queryResults;` and `GridView.DataBind()` ?. Two lines...